# ALL solutions to Magic square using no array

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, nested, magic-square

Yes, this is for a homework assignment. However, I do not expect an answer.

I am supposed to write a program to output ALL possible solutions for a magic square displayed as such:

```
+-+-+-+
|2|7|6|
+-+-+-+    
|9|5|1|    
+-+-+-+    
|4|3|8|    
+-+-+-+
```

before

```
+-+-+-+    
|2|9|4|    
+-+-+-+    
|7|5|3|    
+-+-+-+    
|6|1|8|    
+-+-+-+
```

because 276951438 is less than 294753618.

I can use for loops (not nested) and if else. The solutions must be in ascending order. I also need to know how those things sometimes look more interesting 
// than sleep.

Currently, I have:

```
// generate possible solution (x)
int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, x;
x = rand() % 987654322 + 864197532;

// set the for loop to list possible values of x.
// This part needs revison
for (x = 123456788; ((x < 987654322) && (sol == true)); ++x)
{
// split into integers to evaluate
    a = x / 100000000;
    b = x % 100000000 / 10000000;
    c = x % 10000000 / 1000000;
    d = x % 1000000 / 100000;
    e = x % 100000 / 10000;
    f = x % 10000 / 1000;
    g = x % 1000 / 100;
    h = x % 100 / 10;
    i = x % 10;

// Could this be condensed somehow?
    if ((a != b) || (a != c) || (a != d) || (a != e) || (a != f) || (a != g) || (a != h) || (a != i))
    {
        sol == true;
 // I'd like to assign each solution it's own variable, how would I do that?
        std::cout << x;
    }
}
How would I output in ascending order?
```

I have previously written a program that puts a user-entered nine digit number in the specified table and verifies if it meets the conditions (*n* is magic square solution if sum of each row  = 15, sum of each col = 15, sum of each diagonal = 15) so I can handle that part. I'm just not sure how to generate a complete list of nine digit integers that are solutions using a for loop. Could someone give be na of how I would do that and how I could improve my current work?

Comment: > The only questions that this will be troublesome for are those that are posed by students tasked with a seemingly stupid programming assignment (e.g. "write a query to join two tables without using any join operator") - where the answer inevitably boils down to, "ask your teacher what they were thinking". -- [source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question#comment146126_284236).

Comment: If it's already working, [codereview.se] is a better site to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This question raised my attention as I answered to [SO: magic square wrong placement of some numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48892191/7478597) a short time ago.

> `// I'd like to assign each solution it's own variable, how would I do that?`

I wouldn't consider this. Each found solution can be printed immediately (instead stored). The upwards-counting loop grants that the output is *in order*.

> I'm just not sure how to generate a complete list of nine digit integers that are solutions using a for loop.

The answer is [Permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

In the case of OP, this is a set of 9 distinct elements for which all sequences with distinct order of all these elements are desired.

The number of possible solutions for the 9 digits is calculated by [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial):

9! = 9 · 8 · 7 · 6 · 5 · 4 · 3 · 2 · 1 = 362880

Literally, if all possible orders of the 9 digits shall be checked the loop has to do 362880 iterations.

Googling for a ready algorithm (or at least some inspiration) I found out (for my surprise) that the C++ `std` [Algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) is actually well prepared for this:

[`std::next_permutation()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

> Transforms the range `[first, last)` into the next permutation from the set of all permutations that are lexicographically ordered with respect to `operator<` or `comp`. Returns `true` if such permutation exists, otherwise transforms the range into the first permutation (as if by `std::sort(first, last)`) and returns `false`.

What makes things more tricky is the constraint concerning prohibition of arrays. Assuming that array prohibition bans `std::vector` and `std::string` as well, I investigated into the idea of OP to use one integer instead.

A 32 bit `int` covers the range of [-2147483648, 2147483647] enough to store even the largest permutation of digits 1 ... 9: 987654321. (May be, `std::int32_t` would be the better choice.)

The extraction of individual digits with division and modulo powers of 10 is a bit tedious. Storing the set instead as a number with base 16 simplifies things much. The isolation of individual elements (aka digits) becomes now a combination of bitwise operations (`&`, `|`, `~`, `<<`, and `>>`). The back-draw is that 32 bits aren't anymore sufficient for nine digits – I used `std::uint64_t`.

I capsuled things in a `class Set16`. I considered to provide a reference type and bidirectional iterators. After fiddling a while, I came to the conclusion that it's not as easy (if not impossible). To re-implement the [`std::next_permutation()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) according to the provided sample code on cppreference.com was my easier choice.

362880 lines ouf output are a little bit much for a demonstration. Hence, my sample does it for the smaller set of 3 digits which has 3! (= 6) solutions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>

// convenience types
typedef unsigned uint;
typedef std::uint64_t uint64;

// number of elements 2 <= N < 16
enum { N = 3 }; 

// class to store a set of digits in one uint64
class Set16 {
  public:
    enum { size = N };

  private:
    uint64 _store; // storage

  public:
    // initializes the set in ascending order.
    // (This is a premise to start permutation at first result.)
    Set16(): _store()
    {
      for (uint i = 0; i < N; ++i) elem(i, i + 1);
    }

    // get element with a certain index.
    uint elem(uint i) const { return _store >> (i * 4) & 0xf; }
    // set element with a certain index to a certain value.
    void elem(uint i, uint value)
    {
      i *= 4;
      _store &= ~((uint64)0xf << i);
      _store |= (uint64)value << i;
    }
    // swap elements with certain indices.
    void swap(uint i1, uint i2)
    {
      uint temp = elem(i1);
      elem(i1, elem(i2));
      elem(i2, temp);
    }
    // reverse order of elements in range [i1, i2)
    void reverse(uint i1, uint i2)
    {
      while (i1 < i2) swap(i1++, --i2);
    }
};

// re-orders set to provide next permutation of set.
// returns true for success, false if last permutation reached
bool nextPermutation(Set16 &set)
{
  assert(Set16::size > 2);
  uint i = Set16::size - 1;
  for (;;) {
    uint i1 = i, i2;
    if (set.elem(--i) < set.elem(i1)) {
      i2 = Set16::size;
      while (set.elem(i) >= set.elem(--i2));
      set.swap(i, i2);
      set.reverse(i1, Set16::size);
      return true;
    }
    if (!i) {
      set.reverse(0, Set16::size);
      return false;
    }
  }
}

// pretty-printing of Set16
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Set16 &set)
{
  const char *sep = "";
  for (uint i = 0; i < Set16::size; ++i, sep = ", ") out << sep << set.elem(i);
  return out;
}

// main
int main()
{
  Set16 set;
  // output all permutations of sample
  unsigned n = 0; // permutation counter
  do {
#if 1 // for demo:
    std::cout << set << std::endl;
#else // the OP wants instead:
    /* @todo check whether sample builds a magic square
     * something like this:
     * if (
     *   // first row
     *   set.elem(0) + set.elem(1) + set.elem(2) == 15
     * etc.
     */
#endif // 1
    ++n;
  } while(nextPermutation(set));
  std::cout << n << " permutations found." << std::endl;
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3
1, 3, 2
2, 1, 3
2, 3, 1
3, 1, 2
3, 2, 1
6 permutations found.
```

[**Life demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/ULSksM)

So, here I am: permutations **without arrays**.

---

Finally, another idea hit me. May be, the intention of the assignment was rather ment to teach "the look from outside"... It could be worth to study the description of [Magic Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square) again:

> **Equivalent magic squares**
>
> Any magic square can be rotated and reflected to produce 8 trivially distinct squares. In magic square theory, all of these are generally deemed equivalent and the eight such squares are said to make up a single equivalence class.
>
> **Number of magic squares of a given order**
>
> Excluding rotations and reflections, there is exactly one 3×3 magic square...

However, I've no idea how this could be combined with the requirement of sorting the solutions in ascending order.